# Lombok compilation error on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, lombok

I am trying to introduce Lombok into my project. Everything builds fine when I compile it locally but on Jenkins it reports this problem and then it fail on all the getters and setter which I replaced with `@Data` anotation. Jenkins uses Java 1.8. Any idea what might be wrong?

```
[INFO] Compiling 154 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MERGE REQUEST build error_prone/workspace/com.betradar.betpal.server.app.api/target/classes
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MERGE REQUEST build error_prone/workspace/com.betradar.betpal.server.app.api/src/main/java/com/betradar/betpal/server/app/message/ObjectFactory.java:22: warning: lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor could not be initialized. Lombok will not run during this compilation: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.errorprone.MaskedClassLoader$1$1 extends com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager
public class ObjectFactory {
       ^
    at lombok.javac.apt.LombokFileObjects.getCompiler(LombokFileObjects.java:148)
    at lombok.javac.apt.InterceptingJavaFileManager.<init>(InterceptingJavaFileManager.java:40)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Errorprone uses the java9 compiler under the hood. There are two possible solutions:

- Upgrade the Lombok dependency to 1.16.20
- Downgrade the errorprone dependency

Comment: I am using Lombok 1.16.20 and getting the exception which is mentioned above. Is there some way how to modify errorprone to avoid complaining about Lombok?